# How do I update the auto hot keys config once saved from a script?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a shortcut to open the current running script in a text editor and then save it and close it. Upon closing, how do I update ahk to use the new updated settings?

This is what I have:

```
        IfWinExist, test.ahk    ahk_exe notepad.exe
        {
            WinActivate
            Sleep, 100
            Send, ^s
            Sleep, 200
            WinClose
        }
        else
            MsgBox, window not found

        app1Open=false
        Reload
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restart the script itself (that is, from its own process), use the [`Reload`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Reload.htm) command.
Otherwise, if you want to restart the script from another process, you have to close it and then run the script again. In this case, you can either [kill the script's process](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm) and run it again (not nice!). Or you can tell the script to gracefully `Reload`, for example in one of these two ways:

- Inter-process communication: [`OnMessage()`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm) for the receiving process and [PostMessage/SendMessage](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm) in the sending process
- Defining a simple hotkey in your receiving script and sending that hotkey from another process

Answer (score 0):

As MCL mentioned, use Reload. There is no need to close the script. Here is an example:

```
^!#r:: ; Save and Reload the script with Alt+Ctrl+Win+r
    IfWinExist, SciTE4AutoHotKey
    {
        WinActivate
        Sleep, 100
        Send, ^s
        Sleep, 300
    }
    Reload
Return
```

Comment: Just realized that SciTE4AutoHotKey might be unclear. This the the editor I use for AHK.

Comment: Why the sleeps? are they necessary?

Comment: Strictly speaking not the first one. If you use controlsend, you don't even need to activate the AHK editor, just send a Ctrl+s to the editor. I used the sleep after saving, just to be sure that the file was written to (SSD) disk before reloading AHK. Don't forget, you are sending a Ctrl+s to an external editor, so this is not something where AHK will wait till the (save) command has been finished. After sending Ctrl+s, it would immediately try to reload.